# Blocking inbound traffic for AWS VPC except from load balancer and select addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I have a couple of HTTP services running in containers using AWS Fargate. These services are meant to be accessed using an Application Load Balancer, and from a list of selected IP addresses. However, with default settings, the services are open to all inbound traffic.

The containers are all in the same VPC, Security Group and Subnets. The same goes for the load balancer.

I tried restricting the inbound traffic using Network ACLs, but this also blocked connections from the load balancer. What is the correct way of achieving the desired behavior (blocking external traffic)?

Comment: What are the current security group rules applied to the load balancer, and the Fargate tasks?

Comment: @MarkB Everything uses the default group, which allows all traffic, inbound and outbound

Comment: Well there's your entire problem, you need to define security groups that only allow the traffic you want.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, but my last attempt left the load balancer unable to connect to the containers, so I'm asking what the right approach is.

Comment: You need to use separate security groups for your load balancer and the Fargate tasks. Using the same security group for everything isn't going to let you accomplish the level of security you want.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, that did the trick, thank you. It seems that the setup doesn't work when I use the default security group for the fargate tasks, which is weird - an identical non-default group works just the way I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ECS tasks and service supports security groups. So you update the "Inbound traffic" of the security group to allow traffic only from ALB, read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-application-load-balancer.html

Comment: Yes, this helps. The key takeaways are 1) use separate security groups for the LB and the Fargate tasks 2) do not use the default security group 3) it is possible to use other security groups as sources in security group access rules

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case it is better to use AWS WAF,  If you want to allow some web requests and block others based on the IP addresses that the requests originate from, create an IP match condition for the IP addresses that you want to allow and another IP match condition for the IP addresses that you want to block. see the following link: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-web-acl-ip-conditions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I managed to achieve what I needed using security groups. But I will check WAF out, too.